# Jinja2 is treating list of dictionary as string

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I am using ansible to parse a jinja2 template. The jinja2 template has a piece of code which should iterate over a variable which is a list of dicts. However it is treating the list of dict as string and printing the individual characters. Please note the variable is set_fact in the ansible playbook.

Code to loop on the list of dicts in the j2 template:

```
{% for subscriber in subscribers %}
{% for dict_item in subscriber['filter_policy'] %}

    {{dict_item.name}}

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Variable as output in the debug module of ansible:

```
 subscribers": [
        {
            "filter_policy": "[  {    \"name\": \"Severity\",    \"type\": \"CommaDelimitedList\",    \"value\": \"critical\"  },  {    \"name\": \"Environment\",    \"type\": \"CommaDelimitedList\",    \"value\": \"nonprod\"  }]",
            "id": "blah@blah.com"
        }
    ]
```

Ansible gives me an error saying:
    "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'str object' has no attribute 'name'"

However if I use set in the jinja2 template to assign the same value to the variable and use for loop over it, it works fine.

```
{% set policies = [{"name": "Severity","type": "CommaDelimitedList","value": "critical"},{"name": "Environment","type": "CommaDelimitedList","value": "nonprod"}] %}
```

I have no clue, how to resolve it.

```
ansible 2.7.2
python version = 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:39) [Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `filter_policy` variable effectively contains a string which happens to be a json representation of a list of dicts. You just have to decode that json string to an effective list of dicts with the [`from_json` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data)

```
{% for subscriber in subscribers %}
{% for dict_item in (subscriber['filter_policy'] | from_json) %}

    {{dict_item.name}}

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Can't believe I spent a whole evening doing this.